# Getting CMake to output Dylib or Framework with Bitcode

Tags: cmake, dylib

In building a framework for use in an mac/tv/iOS project I decided to build a framework and include bitcode, just in case. However, my output framework doesn't contain bitcode.

I can see `-fembed-bitcode` is being called on each source file but when I check the `.dylib` with `otool -l library.dylib` there are no `__LLVM` sections. Switching to creating a static library I can see the `__LLVM` sections.

Why isn't cmake correctly building the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to correctly build the dynamic library whether in a framework or not you need to look at the last line of output from cmake. There you'll see `clang` called with all the `.o` files and the output file being the `.dylib`. This line is missing `-fembed-bitcode` and when linking the library you need to again pass the `-fembed-bitcode` flag.

So by adding the flag to the compile target and library linking correctly adds bitcode.

```
target_compile_options( library PUBLIC -fembed-bitcode )
target_link_options( library PUBLIC -fembed-bitcode )
```